# Conditionally Transpose

Tags: vba, excel, transpose, unpivot

I have a table that looks like this:

```
SKU    ID1    ID2    ID3    ID4     and so on...
111    1ab    2bc    3bc                                
222    1bb    3bb    4bb    abb
333    2bb    3bb    4bc    abc
444    1b2    2bb
```

I am trying to format all of the data as below, hopefully with some kind of macro:

```
SKU    ID
111    1ab                      
111    2bc
111    3bc  
222    1bb
222    3bb
222    4bb
222    abb
333    2bb
333    3bb
333    4bc
333    abc
444    1b2
444    2bb
```

I have tried transposing all of it at once, but it does not come out right. I think a more coded macro type solution is needed, but I am not sure.

Comment: You can use the [Power Query](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379) Excel add-in from Microsoft to perform an [Unpivot](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Unpivot-columns-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098)

Comment: It can also be done with worksheet formulas alone, though depending on the size of your dataset, this may not be the most effective solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an image of Sheet1:

[image]

Here is the code in Sheet1's module:

```
Public Sub ProcessData()
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim OutRow As Long
    Dim DataRow As Long
    Dim DataCol As Long
    Dim SKU As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rData = .Range("D1:J10") ' deliberately larger than the data, as a deminstration
        OutRow = 1
        For DataRow = 2 To rData.Rows.Count
            SKU = rData(DataRow, 1)
            If SKU = 0 Then
                Exit For
            End If
            For DataCol = 2 To rData.Columns.Count
                If Not IsEmpty(rData(DataRow, DataCol)) Then
                    OutRow = OutRow + 1
                    .Cells(OutRow, 1) = SKU
                    .Cells(OutRow, 2) = rData(DataRow, DataCol)
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

This should give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the process detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543651/1505120) but finish off with addressing those data rows that are shorter than others (fewer cells populated) by filtering `Value` to select `(Blanks)` and deleting those rows.